# Trying to connect MySQL database but can never load any DLL files

Tags: php, mysql, database, dll

It throws this: "PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_mysqli.dll' (tried: C:\Program Files\php\ext\php_mysqli.dll". 
It searches in EXACTLY the right location for it to find it, and still doesn't find it. I've searched through dozens of similar pages and nothing has resolved my issue. I am running Windows with the latest php 7.4 version.

What I've done:

- Went into php.ini and set the directory path to "C:\Program Files\php\ext", and yes, all my dll's are located there
- tried commenting and uncommenting extension=mysqli
- added "extension=php_mysqli.dll" to php.ini file and commented and uncommented it
- Tried using PDO instead but it still fails to load corresponding DLL's
- set my IDE's (Eclipse) PHP exe path to CLI and CGI and set the path to the php.ini

And because it cannot load the mysqli.dll for no apparent reason, mysqli_connect() is still not a defined function. Again, other pages reporting the same errors did not resolve this for me. Is the problem my IDE (Eclipse)?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that the dynamic loading of all the modules in the php\ext folder wasn't the culprit. Because the file php_mysql.dll wasn't in that folder, so it couldn't be loaded from there. After further analyses it seems that in the latest PHP (7.02) download for Windows 64-bit the php.ini file still contains this:

```
[PHP_MYSQL]
extension=php_mysql.dll
```

After commenting out the section the error in the log file was gone. As we obviously can't load that dll file anymore.

```
;[PHP_MYSQL]
;extension=php_mysql.dll
```

Comment: So you are saying I should comment out those 2 lines? I know I've tried that before

Comment: Uday, this is the result.
"X-Powered-By: PHP/7.4.5
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8" with no actual output after that. Is this expected? Did it really work or did it run without accomplishing the connection?